# Need some explanation on different use case people use in testing

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermockito

What i understood is :
@Mock creates a mock object which is equivalent to `Mockito.mock()`
Similary 
@Spy is equivalent to `Mockito.spy()`

@InjectMocks inject the mock dependecy into a class and created a new object to the class in which mock dependeny are injecting.

I have seen some code where @InjectMocks `Class class = Mockito.mock(ClassName.class);` or @InjectMocks `Class class = Mockito.spy(ClassName.class);`

Also what is the difference between `Mockito.spy(ClassName.class)` and `Mockito.spy(new ClassName());`

Answer (score 0):

The `InjectMocks` for `mocked` object will inject the mock dependencies into the mocked class.

The `mocked` object doesn't have any implementation for the behaviors (methods), you need to declare them using `when(....).then(....)`

```
@InjectMocks Class class = Mockito.mock(ClassName.class);
```

, will `InjectMocks` for `spy` object will inject the mock dependencies into a class and use the real object's implementation of behaviors (methods) unless you override that using `when(....).then(....)`

```
@InjectMocks Class class = Mockito.spy(ClassName.class);
```